# Slow window drawing for specific application on RDS server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v, rds

I have a specific application required on a RDS server so remote users can access the data it stores.
This is a server and client solution, and I am having issues with the client.

If the client is installed on a normal Windows 7 installation on bare-metal, we have no issues at all. Application feels snappy, and opens windows instantly.
When installed on a RDS server, it takes about 20sec to draw any changes in the application window, and the application appears to "freeze".
Also the background color is missing from within the application window itself, which you would normally have.
None of the compatibility modes fixes the issue.

The RDS server is a Windows Server 2008R2 machine hosted by Windows Server 2012R2 under Hyper-v. I have allocated 8GB RAM and 4vCPUs, and VMQ is disabled, and a local gigabit connection to the host. When I did my testing, I was the only user logged in.

I noticed when the application window was "freezing", resources were just as low as before.
As a test, I started the RDS server in safe mode with networking and tested the application from within the hyper-v manager.
Responsiveness was perfect, changes in the application was updated instantly and the application no longer appears to be freezing.

If I disable the video adapter in the device manager, and restart the RDS normally (but still log in via the hyper-v management console) I can get the application to behave normally under the resolution 640x480.
Any higher and it goes back to "freezing".

There is a similar post here (first post): http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1932577 with the same behavior as I am experiencing with my application.

Could implementation of window drawing is to blame here, and are there any known workarounds?

Comment: Microsoft developed RemoteFX for this very scenario. To implement it, you need to make sure your Hyper-V hosts supports the RemoteFX hardware requirements. If it doesn't, there probably isn't much you can do to improve the performance. - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff817578(v=ws.10).aspx - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff817602(WS.10).aspx